# How can I get .htaccess hot link blocking to work?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, hotlinking

I want to block access to a direct .exe file located on my server that a third party site has been hot linking from me

I've tried a lot of the answers on here that have to do with image hot lininkg and none have worked thus far Ex:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?evildomain\.com(/.*)*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|JPEG|exe|EXE|jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|png|PNG|mng|MNG)$ - [F]
```

When using the above code hot linking still works for the site in question (not mine)

Comment: Have you checked the requests to see if they include a referrer at all? It's not uncommon for malicious sites to mask the referrer via a JavaScript redirect to prevent this sort of detection. Frankly, I'd put the `.exe` behind a captcha, or change its URL occasionally.

Comment: Ill probably just start changing the url occasionally, the site has a ripped off domain from mine just adding "download" to it. like exampledownload.com and has a hyperlink that links directly to my download. Kinda annoying. Thanks for the help

Comment: You might also consider switching your logic and *requiring* a HTTP referrer *from your own site*, as you can be reasonably assured that'll be present.

Comment: This is great. A proprietary executable that is hot linked. Can't stop laughing about this. So there is a "malicious" site actively hot linking an unknown application where no one can say what it contains. Who clicks such link? And executes an application he downloaded that way? It is absurd to do so. And then people wonder why MS-Windows systems always get infected. Strange how that can happen...

Comment: In general there is no robust solution for what you ask based only on the evaluation of http headers. Those can be easily tempered if such "malicious" site wants to. Robust approaches require either a form of authorization of at least some real session management.